# What are the Design Patterns used In Joomla?

Tags: joomla-3.x, design-patterns

This question can be **vague**, so i narrow down and list down **some points** i want to know.

> 1. What are the design patterns used in Joomla (Just a list of them).
> 2. In Which section of Joomla architecture those design patterns are used. (Indication only).

Some of the design pattern i noticed that are used in Joomla are **singleton**, **factory** and **observer**. I know there are **some other** too, so i want to know them. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting question,  I hope this thread get some traction; as it is one I've asked periodically throughout my years working with Joomla.   It's also a topic I feel which can provide insights to all levels of programmers.

When I asked a far more experienced programmer the same question, he said Joomla has lots of examples of hybrid and loose implementation with a few pure examples.

Now for my two sense!

MVC Architectural Pattern - probably most popular paradigm for structuring an application and its files for software development currently.

Command Pattern - The JHtml::_ and JText::_ classes resemble this pattern, although I'm not well versed on its official class diagram and would appreciate any insights.

Registry Pattern & Abstract Factory Pattern - An example of a hybrid approach I mentioned earlier in my opinion, in that the intent mimics the patterns but execution doesn't follow UML to the letter.  JFactory would be the class which I'm referencing.

Strategy Pattern - A good example of this would be how JDatabase abstract factory handles implementation of database drivers through separation of concerns.

Now that you have peeked my interest on this topic again I will try and do some more research and hope other more knowledgeable developers can provide insights, corrections or clarity!

Comment: It's worth to say about Singleton too. For example `JFactory::getDbo()` is based on instance.

Comment: yes, and what about observer pattern in plugin environment.